# Поиск в TableView на Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

У меня есть два массива: `FirstTableArray` (в нем список брендов) и `SecondTableArray` (в нем перечень моделей телефонов).

Мне нужно создать *Search Bar*, в котором можно будет найти модель телефона по части названия.

Кто-то может помочь реализовать это? Вот мой код:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var FirstTableArray = [String]()
    var SecondTableArray = [SecondTable]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

// First Table Array

    FirstTableArray = ["Apple", "Samsung"]

// Second Table Array

    SecondTableArray = [
    SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["iPhone 5s", "iPhone 6", "iPhone 6s"]),
    SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["Galaxy S4", "Galaxy S5", "Galaxy S6"]), 
    ]   
    }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
    return FirstTableArray.count
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    Cell.textLabel?.text = FirstTableArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    return Cell
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let indexPath : IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let DestViewController = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController
    let SecondTableArrayTwo = SecondTableArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    DestViewController.SecondTableArray = SecondTableArrayTwo.SecondTitle
    } 
}
```

Comment: А что не получилось реализовать? Что попробовали сделать с SearchBar?

Comment: Вывести SearchBar получается. Пробовал по разным туториалам (например http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/). С этим разобрался. Не понимаю как обработать конкретно массив SecondTableArray, что бы поиск выводил данные непосредственно с него.